# What is wrong with my subroutines?

Tags: vb.net

So I've been working on this project for a couple of weeks, as I self teach.  I've hit a wall, and the community here has been so helpful I come again with a problem.

Basically, I have an input box where a user inputs a name.  The name is then displayed in a listbox.  The name is also put into an XML table if it is not there already.

There is a button near the list box that allows the user to remove names from the list box.  This amends the XML, not removing the name from the table, but adding an end time to that name's child EndTime.
If the user then adds the same name to the input box, the XML gets appended to add another StartTime rather than create a new element.

All of this functions well enough (My code is probably clunky, but it's been working so far.)  The problem comes when I try to validate the text box before passing everything through to XML.  What I am trying to accomplish is that if the name exists in the listbox on the form (i.e hasn't been deleted by the user) then nothing happens to the XML, the input box is cleared.  This is to prevent false timestamps due to a user accidentally typing the same name twice.

Anyhow, I hope that makes sense, I'm tired as hell.  The code I've got is as follows:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_2(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles addPlayerButton.Click
    playerTypeCheck()
    addPlayerXML()
    clearAddBox()
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub playerTypeCheck()
    If playerTypeCBox.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        addMiner()
    ElseIf playerTypeCBox.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        addHauler()
    ElseIf playerTypeCBox.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        addForeman()
    End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub addMiner()
    If minerAddBox.Text = String.Empty Then
        Return
    End If
    If minerListBox.Items.Contains(UCase(minerAddBox.Text)) = True Then
        Return
    Else : minerListBox.Items.Add(UCase(minerAddBox.Text))
    End If
    If ComboBox1.Items.Contains(UCase(minerAddBox.Text)) = True Then
        Return
    Else : ComboBox1.Items.Add(UCase(minerAddBox.Text))
    End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub addPlayerXML()

    If System.IO.File.Exists("Miners.xml") Then
        Dim xmlSearch As New XmlDocument()
        xmlSearch.Load("Miners.xml")
        Dim nod As XmlNode = xmlSearch.DocumentElement()

        If minerAddBox.Text = "" Then
            Return

        Else
            If playerTypeCBox.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
                nod = xmlSearch.SelectSingleNode("/Mining_Op/Miners/Miner[@Name='" + UCase(minerAddBox.Text) + "']")
            ElseIf playerTypeCBox.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
                nod = xmlSearch.SelectSingleNode("/Mining_Op/Haulers/Hauler[@Name='" + UCase(minerAddBox.Text) + "']")
            ElseIf playerTypeCBox.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
                nod = xmlSearch.SelectSingleNode("/Mining_Op/Foremen/Foreman[@Name='" + UCase(minerAddBox.Text) + "']")
            End If

            If nod IsNot Nothing Then
                nodeValidatedXML()
            Else
                    Dim docFrag As XmlDocumentFragment = xmlSearch.CreateDocumentFragment()
                    Dim cr As String = Environment.NewLine
                    Dim newPlayer As String = ""
                    Dim nod2 As XmlNode = xmlSearch.SelectSingleNode("/Mining_Op/Miners")

                    If playerTypeCBox.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
                        newMinerXML()
                    ElseIf playerTypeCBox.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
                        newHaulerXML()
                    ElseIf playerTypeCBox.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
                        newForemanXML()
                    End If

                End If

        End If
    Else
        newXML()

    End If

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub nodeValidatedXML()
    If playerTypeCBox.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        minerValidatedXML()
    ElseIf playerTypeCBox.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        haulerValidatedXML()
    ElseIf playerTypeCBox.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        foremanValidatedXML()
    End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub minerValidatedXML()
    If minerListBox.Items.Contains(UCase(minerAddBox.Text)) = False Then
        appendMinerTimeXML()
    End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub appendMinerTimeXML()
    Dim xmlSearch As New XmlDocument()
    xmlSearch.Load("Miners.xml")
    Dim docFrag As XmlDocumentFragment = xmlSearch.CreateDocumentFragment()
    Dim cr As String = Environment.NewLine
    Dim newStartTime As String = Now & ", "
    Dim nod2 As XmlNode = xmlSearch.SelectSingleNode("/Mining_Op/Miners/Miner[@Name='" & UCase(minerAddBox.Text) & "']/StartTime")
    docFrag.InnerXml = newStartTime
    nod2.AppendChild(docFrag)
    xmlSearch.Save("Miners.xml")
End Sub
```

---

And lastly, the clearAddBox() subroutine

```
Private Sub clearAddBox()
    minerAddBox.Text = ""
End Sub
```

---

So, I should point out, that if I rewrite the nodeValidated() Subroutine to something like:

```
Private Sub nodeValidatedXML()
    If playerTypeCBox.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        appendMinerTimeXML()
    ElseIf playerTypeCBox.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        appendHaulerTimeXML()
    ElseIf playerTypeCBox.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        appendForemanTimeXML()
    End If
End Sub
```

---

then all of the XML works, except it adds timestamps on names that already exist in the list, which is what i'm trying to avoid.  So if I haven't completely pissed you off yet, what is it about the minerValidated() subroutine that is failing to call appendMinerTimeXML()?  I feel the problem is either in the minerValidated() sub, or perhaps clearAddBox() is somehow firing and I'm missing it?  Thanks for taking the time to slog through this.

Edit: Clarification.  The code as I have it right now is failing to append the XML at all.  Everything writes fine the first time, but when I remove a name from the list and then re-add, no timestamp is added to the XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to prevent the user accidentally typing the name twice.(Not sure if you mean adding it twice)

For this I believe you need to clear the `minerAddBox.Text` in your `addminer()` if this line is true.

```
minerListBox.Items.Contains(UCase(minerAddBox.Text)) = True
minerAddBox.Text = ""
Return
```

Now it will return back to your `addplayerXML` which will Return to your `clearbox()`, since you have this in your `addplayerXML()`

```
If minerAddBox.Text = "" Then
Return
```

Now you get to your `clearbox()` (Which is not really needed now since you cleared the `minerAddBox.Text` already)

2. *when I remove a name from the list and then re-add, no timestamp is added to the XML.*

your `minerValidatedXML()` is true, because you are not clearing the textbox when you re-add a name to the list box. Or you may need to remove the existing listbox item if it is the same as the textbox

```
If minerListBox.Items.Contains(UCase(minerAddBox.Text)) = True Then
   minerListBox.Items.remove(UCase(minerAddBox.Text))
```

Comment: I think I see what you're driving at.  The flow is jumbled in my head right now, and I think I need to study the return command a bit more so I can understand the flow of my code better.  I'll play with this a bit today.  Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I got it.  It was definitely a flow thing.  Since it was passing playerTypeCheck() first, it was populating the list before passing the addPlayerXML(), and the minerValidatedXML() was returning true.  Changing the order of the sub calls on the button push fixed the problem.  I do want to keep the clearbox() sub so that way when a name is entered the box clears and the user can type another without deleting.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Jack If the answer helps you then upvote. If the answer solves your problem than also Accept his Answer.